# Why can't I use a compatible concrete type when implementing an interface

Tags: c#, class, interface

I would like to be able to do something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public interface IFoo
    {
        IEnumerable<int> integers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar : IFoo
    {
        public List<int> integers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why does the compiler complains..?

```
Error   2   'Test.Bar' does not implement interface member 'Test.IFoo.integers'. 'Test.Bar.integers' cannot implement 'Test.IFoo.integers' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'.
```

I understand that the interface says IEnumerable and the class uses a List, but a List *is* an IEnumerable.....

what can I do? I do not want to specify IEnumerable in the class, I want to use a concrete type that implements IEnumerable, like List...

Comment: "I want to use a concrete type that implements IEnumerable, like List..." -- why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a Type Covariance/Contravariance issue (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#C.23 ).

There's a workaround: use explicit interfaces, like so:

```
public class Bar : IFoo {

    private IList<int> _integers;

    IEnumerable<int> IFoo.integers {
        get { return _integers };
        set { _integers = value as IList<int>; }
    }

    public IList<int> integers {
        get { return _integers; }
        set { _integers = vale; }
    }
}
```

Note that `integers` should be TitleCased to conform to .NET's guidelines.

Hopefully you can see the problem in the code above: `IList<int>` is compatible with `IEnumerable<int>` only for the accessor, but not for setting. What happens if someone calls `IFoo.integers = new Qux<int>()` (where `Qux : IEnumerable<int>` but **not** `Qux : IList<int>`).

Comment: This turns out to be extremely useful when dealing with the issue of deserializing JSON objects into a concrete object that has to have interface parameters.  By providing the concrete parameters as well, the deserializer can figure out a way to instantiate an object for the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Although List implements IEnumerable that's not the way interfaces work.  The interface specifies exactly which types need to be exposed for properties.  If you created a generic interface like

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : IEnumerable<int>
{
    T integers { get; set; }
}
```

You could then use `IFoo<List<int>>` to implement it in the way you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You're not going to be able to use a concrete type unless you do it behind the scenes. The problem is that you can both Get and Set the Property.

Your interface specifies that the property is of type `IEnumerable<int>`. `HashSet<int>` implements `IEnumerable<int>`. That means the following should work just fine:

```
IFoo instance = new Bar();
instance.integers = new HashSet<int>();
```

But since you're trying to implement the interface using the concrete type `List<int>`, there's no way that assignment can work.

The easiest fix, assuming you don't constantly need to re-assign the collection, would be to only specify a getter for the collection:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IEnumerable<int> Integers { get; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public List<int> Integers { get; private set; }

    public Bar(List<int> list)
    {
        Integers = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that this works (I can't test it right now), but I don't understand why.  Why would removing the setter from the interface allow a `List<int>` to implement an `IEnumerable<int>`?  Does the compiler typecheck in each direction (i.e. you could implement a `List<int> Integers { set; }` with an `IEnumerable<int> Integers { private get; set }`?

Comment: I assume the `Bar` in the sample code implements `IFoo`? If so, the code does not fix the problem. Same compile error : `Test.Bar.Integers' cannot implement Test.IFoo.Integers' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the first line in `Bar` should actually be `public IEnumerable<int> Integers { get; private set; }`, such that it has a type that matches the interface and is constrained by the class to only be a list. The property will still be `IEnumerable<int>` on the `Bar` class. The `List<int>` constraint really only exists under the hood. There's not really anything outside of `Bar` that guarantees a caller will get a `List<int>`.