# Hide multiple classes behind one interface

Tags: c#

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public interface IChildItem
{}

public interface IItem
{
    public EntitySet<IChildItem> Children {get;}
}

public class ChildItem1 : IChildItem
{}

public class ChildItem2 : IChildItem
{}

public class Item1 : IItem
{
    public EntitySet<ChildItem1> Children
    {
        get{ return m_children; }
    }
}

public class Item2 : IItem
{
    public EntitySet<ChildItem2> Children
    {
        get{ return m_children; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to hide Item1 and Item2 behind IItem interface.

Main problem is I also need Children property to return list of interfaces (IChildItem). But compiler is saying that the way that I am doing it is not allowable. That `EntitySet<IChildItem> Children {get;}` is missing in classes Item1 and Item2. Why `EntitySet<ChildItem1>` is not equals to `EntitySet<IChildItem>`???

Classes Item1 and Item2 are generated automatically (dbml) that is why I cannot change them.

Is there some kind of trick to help me resolve this?

Comment: Can you change the definition of interfaces?

Comment: @Sergii Zhevzhyk: yes!!

Comment: You could just make a holder class that can hold both Item1 and Item2 and give it a "common" interface.  I think this is called a Facade Pattern

Comment: @walruz can you change this line `public class Item1 : IItem`? or it's a part of generation?

Comment: _"Why `EntitySet<ChildItem1>` is not equals to `EntitySet<IChildItem>`?"_ - because they aren't. When implementing an interface, you must implement the exact same type. That they are covariant does not mean they are the same.

Comment: @Sergii Zhevzhyk: yes, I can do it (using partial class)

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490633/why-cant-i-use-a-compatible-concrete-type-when-implementing-an-interface

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you

Comment: Thanks to everybody!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) and [Covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) to do this

```
public interface IChildItem                                              
{ }                                                                      

public interface IItem<out TChild> where TChild : IChildItem             
{                                                                        
    IEnumerable<TChild> Children { get; }                                
}                                                                        

public class ChildItem1 : IChildItem                                     
{ }                                                                      

public class ChildItem2 : IChildItem                                     
{ }                                                                      

public class Item1 : IItem<ChildItem1>                                   
{                                                                        
    public IEnumerable<ChildItem1> Children                              
    {                                                                    
        get { return null; }                                             
    }                                                                    
}                                                                        

public class Item2 : IItem<ChildItem2>                                   
{                                                                        
    public IEnumerable<ChildItem2> Children                              
    {                                                                    
        get { return null; }                                             
    }                                                                    
}                                                                        

IItem<ChildItem1> variable = new Item1();                                
IItem<IChildItem> variable2 = variable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic interface is the solution:

```
public interface IChildItem
{ }

public interface IItem<T> where T: class
{
    List<T> Children { get; }
}

public class ChildItem1 : IChildItem
{ }

public class ChildItem2 : IChildItem
{ }

public class Item1 : IItem<ChildItem1>
{
    public List<ChildItem1> Children
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}

public class Item2 : IItem<ChildItem2>
{
    public List<ChildItem2> Children
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
}
```